# How to connect a slave device to an RS-485 network without a signal ground reference terminal?

Tags: rs485, modbus

I want to connect a flow meter and a variable frequency drive (VFD) to the same modbus network but the absence of a signal ground reference terminal on the flow meter is causing me some confusion with regards to how to connect/chain the two slave devices.

The master device has a signal ground reference terminal and so connecting the VFD to the network is as per Figure 1, with the cable shield earthed at a single point. In the case of the flow meter, the wiring diagram in Figure 2 only shows connections for the signal cables and the cable shield, suggesting that the signal ground reference conductor is not connected.

The devices are industrial standard electronics: the flow meter is a Siemens FM MAG 5100W with FM MAG 6000 flow transmitter [(link)](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/109804020/sitrans-fm-mag-5100-w?dti=0&pnid=17318&lc=en-WW), and the VFD is an ABB ACS480 [(link)](https://search.abb.com/library/Download.aspx?DocumentID=3AXD50000047392&LanguageCode=en&DocumentPartId=1&Action=Launch).

Questions:

1. is the proposal in Figure 3 correct?
2. or should the reference ground signal conductor (blue) be connected to the earthed shield (via a resistor) instead of the ground reference terminal (R) on the master/controller i.e. treat as if the ground reference terminal is not available (see Figure 4).

[image]

Figure 1: connections for the Variable Frequency Drive showing the signal ground reference terminal

[image]

Figure 2: connections for the flow meter not showing the signal ground reference

[image]

Figure 3: proposal, based on current understanding

[image]

Figure 4: alternate connections for a VFD + master network without the signal ground reference terminal (R)

Comment: This "Flow meter" has some power supply, no? If so, it has a GND connection.

Comment: Yeah it has a 12V DC supply. It is a possible solution but it is notable that this is is not explicitly stated in the manual, from which Figure 2 is taken.

Comment: Well, it needs *some* common ground. Perhaps Fig2 is assuming the devices are having it through power supply.

Comment: Can't say with this info. Why not reveal us what device it is (yes it is a flowmeter but I mean make and model) and where is the link to manual?

Comment: Why is the ground signal important for the RS485 bus? RS485 signals are differentials (not referenced to ground), aren't they?

Comment: @Rodo They are not necessarily galvanically isolated from the rest of the circuit (which is not always the case). So if the "grounds" of the two endpoints can significantly differ in potentials. So forcing a high voltage (relative to the local ground) on these lines will simply burn it.

Comment: You shall link the manuals of the accompanying communication modules, as they are mounted as accessories. You didn't specify which comm. modules you have.

Comment: The VFD is the standard unit that includes the EIA-485 module and is covered in the already linked manual. The flow transmitter has the optional MODBUS RTU RS485 communication module, which is covered in a different manual [(link)](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/44880906/modbus-rtu-rs-485?dti=0&pnid=17318&lc=en-WW)

Answer (score 2):

If those devices are industrial electronics, then they all should have a galvanically isolated RS485/RS422 transceivers. Therefore you do connect A, B and shield on PE (Figure 4.1). Use a shielded twisted pair (2 wires, only) a Profibus cable or similar.

Mostly, all your proposals are wrong.

Keep in mind that you do need an isolated RS485 converter, not a cheap Ali converter (around 2$).

P.S. : You didn't post any datasheet, manual of the devices.

Comment: The devices are industrial standard electronics: the flow meter is a Siemens FM MAG 5100W with FM MAG 6000 flow transmitter [(link)](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/109804020/sitrans-fm-mag-5100-w?dti=0&pnid=17318&lc=en-WW), and the VFD is an ABB ACS480 [(link)](https://search.abb.com/library/Download.aspx?DocumentID=3AXD50000047392&LanguageCode=en&DocumentPartId=1&Action=Launch).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the second fig., the flow-meter has ground that is common to the signal and the shield. So, the shield has to have enough low impedance with the network common (DGND), and establish a reasonable common mode voltage with other nodes on the network. This part is must.

Now you have to decide how that "shield" - of the flow-meter - has to link to the earthly ground / chassis ground. If the flow-meter shield has electrical path to body/chassis/earthly-body, than you want to make sure that gets Earthed somewhere, for the safety.

Leakage from the circuitry to earth should not occur anywhere. However, when it occurs, the leakage should be bypassed (regardless of the circuitry operation) to earth safely. This means, the digital ground and the shield/chassis ground can be connected. In this case, try avoiding ground loop.

Comment: The shield in 2nd fig. is just for noise protection, it doesn't have any other function. It would work even if you don't connect the shield. "So, the shield has to have enough low impedance with the network common (DGND)," , you are absolutely wrong.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Appreciate your thoughts. "absolutely wrong" sounds like you are upset, sorry about that. I would say, "it likely work" or to be certain "it must work", instead of "it would work". How do you suggest the common mode to be sure in range over nodes?

Comment: I am doing RS485 for more than 20yrs, I had never used a 3rd wire. But the true fact is that I have used a non-isolated transceiver just once, because it didn't work. The industrial devices usually are PnP, they have only A,B wires. You won't find it in manuals, but the non-isolated RS485 can be used only for point-to-point, no multidrop - that's why reputable manufacturers don't offer non-isolated devices. If I have to debug, I do pick two wires, wrap them and connect to my USB/RS485 converter, no shield, no GND wire - never had any issue.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič , Once I designed, installed, a large scale monitoring system, using RS485 network. I had no trouble using the twist-pair without common ground, since the termination and driver impedance establishes reference point, until: Long story short, it was a "salt finery", producing Na, Cl, H2, O2 from the sea salt, using 2kA through large cell (guess 8' x8' ) stacks in a floor of a factory. And, every time the process bootstraps, my "proud of" network was not working, at the most important moment. Guess what I had to find.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič , sorry, I had to correct my English, so my question came back after your answer. :) I understand where you are standing. And, I respect your experiences. What I did was more than 30 years ago, used galvanic isolation, bus-ed. I thought I was the best in that area those days, providing something no one could. But, probably not.